# can I Change ct_results() message?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to add a `login triggers` using ASE while following this [site](http://www.sypron.nl/logtrig.html) , everything is working good. but as below mentionned , i got a ct_result() error , can I change the error ?

```
CT-LIBRARY error:
ct_results(): network packet layer: internal net 
library error: Net-Library operation terminated due to
disconnect
When this happens, the ASE errorlog will contain a message like:   
EXECUTE permission denied on object my_proc, database my_db, owner dbo
```

what I want is to change the message to Permission Denied, contact support. can I do that

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, Rob Verschoor talks about this error message.

1) Do you see any error message in the ASE log file?

2) Did you grant permissions to the my_proc stored procedure such as:?

```
 grant execute on my_proc to <user/role>
 go
```

example:

```
 grant execute on my_proc to public
 go
```

Comment: i got a pop up message in ase saying i cannot loging , I want this pop up message to have different name , in log file i got error saying permission denied , I want in the pop message to be shown .. did you understand me ? if not will show you some screenshot

Comment: I see now what you want to achieve. I am not sure how to modify the CT error message as CT-LIBRARY error seems to be a core message.

Comment: uhmm can I send a pop message ? to send a spesific message